# Remote Desktop 2019: new MSRDC Webfeed URL -> no workspace found // Browser or old MSTSC -> Workspace found?

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have kind of a strange issue related to Microsoft Remote Desktop Services running on Server 2019. 
**My Setup:** 4 Session Host, 1 Server for RD Gateway, RD Licensing, RD WebAccess, RD Broker 
When I call the RD Url: https://rds.example.com/rdweb/ I am able to login and I can see the workspaces and connect to them. The same via HTML5. 
 
Now I wanted to use the new Microsoft MSRDC client: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop

 Comparison of the clients: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-app-compare

 But here comes the troubles: That new client can't find my workspaces :( 
I have tried via Email (with _msradc.example.com) and via URL. Nothing :(( 
 I have done some client investigation with the ETL logfiles and could find that log entry: 
`
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://rds.example.com/RDWeb/FeedLogin/WebFeedLogin.aspx', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers: { If-Modified-Since: Tue, 26 Oct 2021 12:44:18 GMT User-Agent: com.microsoft.rdc.windows.msrdc.x64/1.2.2459.0 User-Agent: (Windows; 10.0.19043.0) X-MS-User-Agent: com.microsoft.rdc.windows.msrdc.x64/1.2.2459.0 (Windows; 10.0.19043.0) }
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 WWW-Authenticate: NTLM WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate Date: Tue, 26 Oct 2021 12:44:18 GMT Content-Length: 1344 Content-Type: text/html }
`
"Unauthorized" is missleading I guess...

 Does anybody use the MSRDC client for an on premise RDS 2019 setup? 
 Are there some pitfalls? Did I miss something? 
The MSRDC client itself works, I can connect to a azure AVD/WVD environment without issues.
 **Any idea or hint would be more than highly appreciated** :)

Answer (score 0):

It'a pitty but:

This client currently only supports accessing remote apps and desktops from Azure Virtual Desktop and Windows 365.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop